# No clipping support in XeTeX when I use \animate in Xelatex

Tags: beamer, xetex

When I run the code, it has warnings as "Package xetex.def Warning: No clipping support in XeTeX yet on input line **." Why?

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont,CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=SimHei,ItalicFont=KaiTi]{SimSun}
\setCJKmonofont[BoldFont=SimHei]{SimSun}
\setCJKsansfont{KaiTi}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmonofont{Monaco}
\setsansfont{Trebuchet MS}
\usetheme[width=50pt]{Berkeley}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\aleph$}
\title{中国
\thanks{\scriptsize 中国B (10872051)}}
\author{中国C}
\institute{中国D}
\date{2014年6月2号}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=0.8\textheight]{1}{lambda_all_p}{01}{02}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My example is as follows.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions (as of 2013/02/04) of `xetex.def` include clipping support. Get (frozen) TeXLive-2013 or wait for TL-14 to come out.

Comment: Thanks, then what about Miktex? How can I get the newer xetex.def

Comment: @ytyyutianyun Did you try a pkg database synchronization + pkg update?

Comment: As you say,  I `update` the `maintenance` and I open the `package manager` and I use the pkg database synchronization and find `xetex.def` not installed. I install the `xetex.def` and `refresh FNDB` Now there is no warning. Thanks, :-D. But I have a trifling question. There is no difference in the result of PDF before update and after update. Why there is so many warnings?

Comment: @ytyyutianyun `animate` internally uses `\includegraphics` with the `clip` option, whether there is something to be clipped (to the size of the image bounding box defined in the image files) or not.

Comment: Thanks，I'm curious why my document shows warning about `xetex-def` before because I even don't install `xetex.def`.